# jQuery sortable programmatic manipulation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

When you're dragging a jQuery sortable element, can you programmatically adjust the position of the element being dragged.  I am trying to do this with the following code:

```
var currentPos = parseInt($(elementbeingdragged).css('left'));
$(elementbeingdragged).css('left',(currentPos-2)+'px');
```

However, I am getting some strange results.  Is there a better API method call I can make to the sortable plugin to more reliably adjust the position of the element being dragged?

Thanks

Comment: These questions might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4911124/450127,  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4928002/450127, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2067602/450127